# Automatically resize row if row is used

Tags: excel, vba

I have code which finds a name within a range, then copies and pastes the rows with that name to a different sheet, whether that be 1 or more rows. I want a code that will automatically resize only the rows used but every time I use the Autofit or RowHeight functions, it doesn't do anything at all. No error, but also no change to the way it pastes or row height. I'm hoping someone here knows the way to make it work!

I've tried variations of 
`Rows("5:6000").RowHeight = 15` and
`Rows("5:6000").AutoFit` and 
`With Sheet7
.Range("A5:Z6000").Select
Selection.AutoFit
End With`

Comment: Please provide what you have tried (code) to accomplish your task.

Comment: See edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Target.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you write the clear reference of rows with sheet.

```
Sheet7.Rows("5:6000").AutoFit
```

or

```
Sheet7.Rows("5:6000").RowHeight = 15
```

or

```
Sheet7.Range("A5:Z6000").EntireRow.AutoFit
```

Comment: Unfortunately, these do not work either, and just return the same outcome as earlier

Comment: Also make sure you're resizing rows after copying/pasting and not before.

Comment: I have code that automatically copies and pastes based on what is searched. I was hoping to add code that would automatically resize the rows to fit the words so other people won't have to do that by hand when they search for someone and may have a paragraph within one cell. Is there not a way to do this using VBA?